# Duda con ramas locales git

Tags: git, github

empiezo en el mundo de la programación, y tengo unas dudas con el uso de git. Me he clonado un repo del cual creé una rama para mis desarrollos en GitHub. El problema es que no entiendo bien como funcionan las ramas de git en local.

Al modificar el código en local tengo que seleccionar mi rama o directamente tocar el código descargado?

Dicho de otra forma, cual es el procedimiento habitual a la hora de desarrollar en proyectos con control de versiones git?

Gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Tu pregunta no es clara. No hay un procedimiento habitual, todo depende del modo en que vas a trabajar, del software en local que tengas para sincronizar con Github, etc. Supongamos que vas a desarrollar en local y que luego quieres que las modificaciones se reflejen en Github. Entonces tendrías que modificar el contenido (en local) y luego hacer un commit  o un push a Github para que esos cambios se envíen allí.

Comment: Clonas, tal y como has hecho, te creas tu rama y trabajas en ella, haces todos los commit que consideres y ya lo juntarás a la rama principal cuando estés satisfecho con el resultado. Para todo lo demás, Makigas, fue con quien dejé de hacerme un lío con el git: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jSJ8xhKtfP4 Muy recomendable

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos, creo que con la info que me habéis pasado ya lo voy pillando. 

Answer (score 1):

Cuando inicializamos un proyecto con Git automáticamente nos encontramos en una rama a la que se denomina "master". Tú creas una rama cuando necesitas hacer un cambio en el código y a la vez deseas dejar una versión estable antes de los cambios. Es básicamente crear una copia a partir de un código original y modificar esa copia dejando la original intacta. En este caso la copia seria la nueva rama y la original (suponiendo que creas la rama a partir de ahí) seria la "máster".

En cuanto al procedimiento habitual para desarrollar proyectos con control de versiones git es lo que se muestra aquí:

https://git-scm.com/book/es/v2/Ramificaciones-en-Git-Procedimientos-B%C3%A1sicos-para-Ramificar-y-Fusionar

Comment: Genial! Ese ejemplo ilustra muy bien la solución a mi problema. Mi problema era ese, que no sabía abstraerse e interpretar como funciona en local. Creo que probaré con un ejemplo sencillo en un txt para asentar conocimientos. Gracias de nuevo!